# Troubleshooting up/down key behavior in command prompt / PowerShell

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard

UPDATE: A friend was able to replicate the issue, so it seems it may not be just my machine. Haven't figured out what is in common between the machines that don't work yet.

---

I'm running into a strange issue with command prompt, which also replicates in PowerShell.

The issue occurs when running the node.js tutorials that can be found at http://nodeschool.io, which when run create a menu system that should be navigable by the up/down arrow keys. On another machine (Surface Pro running Windows 10 latest tech preview) this works normally, so I know the software side of the tutorial is fine.

On my main laptop, running Windows 10 Pro, the up/down arrow keys do not move the selection within the menu, though the Enter key does activate the currently selected item.

If I am at the command prompt (rather than in a menu), the up/down arrow keys **do** navigate through the command history, so it doesn't look like the keys themselves are broken.

An additional wrinkle is that when I tested in a Windows 8.1 Hyper-V VM on the same machine, I saw the same behavior...no navigation in the tutorial menu in a command prompt window.

I also tested the same tutorial from a PowerShell window, to see if perhaps it was an issue with the native Windows command prompt, and the same behavior occurs.

I've been using Windows since the 3.x days, and cannot recall running into something like this, and haven't been able to find anything with a bingle search that seems even remotely connected.

Has anyone run into something similar, or can you offer suggestions of where to start with troubleshooting beyond what I've already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to have been an issue in the underlying library used by the tutorials for generating the menu, when running with the newer 4.x version of node.js. The issue is under investigation and being tracked at:

https://github.com/nodeschool/discussions/issues/1448

The missing piece in my troubleshooting, for folks who run into anything similar, is that I had not accounted for the change in the node version number, which went quite suddenly from v0.12.7 to a v4.x.x series. On reflection, it's hardly surprising that this broke some things.

So another reminder to never make assumptions, and always determine all of the differences between where it works and where it doesn't.